# Micronaut's HttpClient: event-loop-group, num-of-threads, thread-factory: how do they work in conjunction?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I come from the Spring Framework and now I'm on a micronaut project. I know very little about netty and its concepts yet and with that I have a doubt that the micronaut documentation is not clear to me.

I'm in doubt about the settings below:

- micronaut.http.client.event-loop-group
- micronaut.http.client.num-of-threads
- micronaut.http.client.thread-factory

I would like to understand:

- Considering that it is possible to define the number of threads of an event-loop-group, does it make sense to configure an event-loop-group and ALSO client.num-of-threads / client.thread-factory?
- If they can be used together: How do they work together?
- If they cannot be used together: How do they differ? What is the most appropriate use case for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `num-of-threads` and `thread-factory` options are only used if you create the client outside of the application context via `HttpClient.create`.

The `event-loop-group` configuration is to tell the client to use a different event loop group than the default. Event loop groups can be configured through `micronaut.netty.event-loops`. See https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/configurationreference.html#io.micronaut.http.netty.channel.DefaultEventLoopGroupConfiguration

Comment: Hey @James Kleeh, thank you for your response. Do you think that eventLoopGroups can be used to implement a Bulkhead Pattern (this is a good use case?)? Can you give me an use case where create a new eventLoopGroup is a good solution?

Comment: I don't understand how a bulkhead pattern could apply to a thread pool, so I'm not sure

Comment: what if I use the micronaut-http-client-jdk instead of netty.
can I use that configuration as well?